# How to pass an argument to dynamically change an IIFE

Tags: javascript

```js
// food object
var food1 = {
  // returns food ingredients.
  getIngredients: function() {
    let ingredients = ["pepper", "salt", "crayfish"];
    return ingredients;
  }
}

var food2 = {
  // returns food ingredients.
  getIngredients: function() {

    let ingredients = ["pepper", "maggi", "oil"];
    return ingredients;
  }
}

var food3 = {
  // returns food ingredients.
  getIngredients: function() {
    let ingredients = ["inzu", "ogiri", "crayfish"];
    return ingredients;
  }
}

var foods = [food1, food2, food3];
var index = 2;
var getMyFoodIngredients = (function(){

let foodIngredients = foods[index].getIngredients();

return (index)=>{ 
foodIngredients = foods[index].getIngredients();

return foodIngredients;}

})();



function removeIngredient(){

let foodIngredients = getMyFoodIngredients(index);

foodIngredients.pop();
console.log(foodIngredients)
}


for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++)
  removeIngredient();
```

The problem with this approach is that  since am using an immediately invoking function(IIFE) the `foodIngredients` is been initialized once but i want the index of `foods[]` to be dynamically initialized and also form a closure

So how do i pass an argument to dynamically change the `foods[]` ingredient

Comment: Don't use an IIFE? Just do something like `function getMyFoodIngredients(foodIndex) { return foods[foodIndex].getIngredients(); }`...

Comment: The variable foodingredient in removeIngredient() gets initialized everytime the removeIngredient() is called.               How do I keep reference of the food ingredient after been poped

Comment: Your `getMyFoodIngredients` function doesn't even work. It completely ignore its arguments and only uses the global `var index = 2`.